# Meteor run iOS error: Error validating package name. Package name must look like: com.company.Name

Tags: javascript, xcode, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to run `meteor run ios` command. But I'm getting the following error:

```
$ meteor run ios

=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Error validating package name. Package name must look like: com.company.Name
   at validatePackageName (/Users/xyz/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.2.3/package/bin/lib/create.js:173:25)
   at Object.exports.create (/Users/xyz/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.2.3/package/bin/lib/create.js:246:12)
   at Api.createPlatform (/Users/xyz/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/6.2.3/package/bin/templates/cordova/Api.js:116:10)
   at
   /Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform.js:198:24
   at _fulfilled
   (/Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done
   (/Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (/Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
   at
   /Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
   at flush
   (/Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
   at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:489:9)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:418:13)
   => awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await
   (/Users/xyz/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2_1.pgpfte++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:56:12)
   at CordovaProject.runCommands (/tools/cordova/project.js:715:22)
   at CordovaProject.addPlatform (/tools/cordova/project.js:372:10)
   at CordovaProject.ensurePlatformsAreSynchronized (/tools/cordova/project.js:403:12)
   at CordovaRunner.checkPlatformsForRunTargets (/tools/cordova/runner.js:26:25)
   at /tools/cli/commands.js:362:21
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
   at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
   at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
   at Object.main.captureAndExit (/tools/cli/main.js:271:29)
   at Command.doRunCommand [as func] (/tools/cli/commands.js:355:10)
   at /tools/cli/main.js:1483:23
```

I tried removing .meteor/local/cordova-build/ but still get the same error.
Does anybody know what this relates to and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you read https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#configuring-your-app?

Comment: yes i did. Even earlier i had created an ipa file for the same project. I made some changes and trying again but getting that error.

Comment: Show you `mobile-config.js` file, please

Comment: Don't add it to comments, just make an edit to your question.

Comment: earlier i had created ipa file without mobile-config.js. Does it really required?After your comment i created mobile-config.js and tried to run meteor run ios but still get the same error.

Comment: I executed meteor run ios device  on my development devices and then archived in xcode for deployment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Styx for your support.
The below commands worked for me

```
rm -rf .meteor/local/
meteor run ios-device
```